# angle of launch to hit the object on desired location in unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics, game-development, unreal-engine4

I am creating a cricket game and I want to implement a bowling logic that is, I want to through the ball to the ground at specified location(should not gain any height it should start moving towards ground as soon as it launched), I have the initial velocity and distance between two points and I am also throwing from a height to the ground can anyone help to determine the formula or a c# script that will help me to do so in **unity3D**.

I tried doing so using projectile, but it starts gaining height and instead of going towards ground directly it first goes to the maximum height and then hit the ground at specified position.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, so instead of using projectile motion in it, I first extracted the position where mouse is clicked on ground using `raycast` and then I simply used `LookAt` method of unity to turn my point of launch's forward direction towards the extracted position or where I want to hit the ball on ground and then simply Instantiated the ball with impulse force towards the point where I want to hit the ball(as the launch point is facing towards that direction only)...